# How to override back button only on single page in cordova 4.0?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I have a requirement, where only on a particular page, i mean when user comes to say in index.html and when he click back button, i need prompt an alert saying do you want to exit from an app. 
If he says 'yes', exit else 'no'. I'm able to achieve this, by overriding the back button and also by checking whether user is in index.html page or not as shown in the below code.

Code Sample:

```
function onLoad() {
    alert("OnLoad");
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReay, false);
}
 function onDeviceReay()
        {   
            var x = document.URL;
            alert(x);
    if( x.indexOf('index') >= 0)
    {
            document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(e){
                      if (confirm("Press a button!"))
                      {
                     alert("You pressed OK!");
                     navigator.app.exitApp();
                      }
                    else
                      {
                        alert("You pressed Cancel!");
                      }
              }, false);
        }
        }
```

But the problem is when the user navigates to other page and then when he clicks on back button, it's not navigating back to previous page.Could someone please shed some light where i'm going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: is the Confirm dialog shows when clicking back button?

Comment: public void onBackPressed() {
      
         //Your code here
    }

Comment: Yes Sonia, it's displaying.

Comment: Sorry DJphy, i didn't get you. Could you please elaborate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in the html page where you need to trigger the back button :

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", leavePage, false); 

    function onPageLeave(buttonIndex) {

        if(buttonIndex==1){
            window.history.back();
        }
        else{   
        }
    }

    function leavePage() {
        navigator.notification.confirm(
            'Would you like to leave  ?', // message
             onPageLeave,            // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
            'Leaving page request',           // title
            ['Yes','No']         // buttonLabels
        );
    }
```

Note that you'll need to notification plugin. Otherwise you could just replace with a simple alert().

Comment: Thanks BipBip, but i'm facing the same problem. its overriding the back button even in other pages as well. I want to override in a single page

Comment: That's weird because this codes works for me only on the page where I put it. It doesn't work in other pages. Are you using it in the ondeviceready function ?